# How can I make background of a button transparent when it is on top of other colored buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

[image: example]

Firstly, this is a windows form application.
As in the picture, I want the background of the Restart button to be transparent and show the colors behind it.
There is no picture.
I created all buttons dynamically

How can I do it, what do you suggest?

Comment: The button is an image or dynamically generated? If it's an image, PNG format should be sufficient. Any pixel in .png can be transparent or partially transparent. In the case of dynamic drawing, transparency in WPF can be achieved using the Opacity parameter. In WinForms, however, I'm not an expert, but the worst-case scenario would be overriding the OnPaint event.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78187059/edit) your question and add a Tag for either **winforms** or **wpf** because the answers would be very different.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms buttons do not support this kind of transparency. What I have done in the past is override `Button` to make a custom behavior where the button is painted to match what's behind it like a cloaking technique.

[image: example]

```
class TransparentButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            // Detect size/location changes
            if ((PointToScreen(Location) != _prevLocation) || (Size != _prevSize))
            {
                bool isInitial = false;
                if ((BackgroundImage == null) || !BackgroundImage.Size.Equals(Size))
                {
                    isInitial = true;
                    BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
                }
                if (MouseButtons.Equals(MouseButtons.None))
                {
                    // Hide button, take screenshot, show button again
                    Visible = false;
                    BeginInvoke(async () =>
                    {
                        Parent?.Refresh();
                        if (isInitial) await Task.Delay(250);
                        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BackgroundImage))
                        {
                            graphics.CopyFromScreen(PointToScreen(new Point()), new Point(), Size);
                        }
                        Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BackgroundImage))
                        graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, graphics.ClipBounds);
                }
            }
            _prevLocation = PointToScreen(Location);
            _prevSize = Size;
        }
    }
    Point _prevLocation = new Point(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
    Size _prevSize = new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

---

**Main Form**

Here's the main form code that puts this snippet in some context.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    Random _rando = new Random(12);
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int row = 0; row < tableLayoutPanel.RowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount; col++)
            {
                var number = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, _rando.Next(1, 9)));
                var button = new Button
                {
                    Name = $"button_{col}_{row}",
                    Tag = number,
                    Text = $"{number}",
                    Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xf,
                    Font = new Font(Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                    BackColor = localGetGradientColor(number)
                };
                tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button,col, row);
                button.Click += Any_Clicked;
                Color localGetGradientColor(int number)
                {
                    Color startColor = Color.FromArgb(0x8E, 0xC6, 0x3F);
                    Color endColor = Color.FromArgb(0x01, 0xAC, 0xC6);
                    float scale = (float)(number - 1) / 256;
                    int r = (int)(startColor.R + (endColor.R - startColor.R) * scale);
                    int g = (int)(startColor.G + (endColor.G - startColor.G) * scale);
                    int b = (int)(startColor.B + (endColor.B - startColor.B) * scale);
                    return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                }
            }
        }
        var buttonRestart = new TransparentButton
        {
            Size = new Size(200,80),
            Text = "Restart",
            Location = new Point(
                (ClientSize.Width - 200) / 2,
                (ClientSize.Height - 80) / 2
            ),
            Font = new Font("Kaushan Script", 18),
        };
        SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            buttonRestart.Location = new Point(
                (ClientSize.Width - 200) / 2,
                (ClientSize.Height - 80) / 2
            );
        };
        buttonRestart.Click += async(sender, e) =>
        {
            buttonRestart.Hide();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));
            buttonRestart.Show();
        };
        Controls.Add(buttonRestart);
        Controls.SetChildIndex(buttonRestart, 0);
    }
    private void Any_Clicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));
    }
}
```